# How to configure Jmeter to write the same data to csv/xml as it is displaying in the Summary Report in the GUI?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a simple Jmeter project configured the way I like it, in regards to the actual load test. But now, when I want to configure Jmeter to log the results to a csv/xml file, I hit a road block. I simply can't figure out how to configure it to log the same data that I see in the GUI.

The listener I use is the "Summary Report". In it, I see things like "**Average**", "**Min**", "**Max**", "**Error %**" and "**Throughput**". All of these are data that I want. But when I click the "**Configure**" button in the "**Write results to file**" box above the results, none of the checkboxes seem to match these columns. How do I get "**Error %**", "**Throughput**" etc written to the file? Instead I see a bunch of unrelated stuff, like "**Save URL**". How is the individual URLs relevant for a **Summary** Report? The summary report is literally one single line of data, but nothing in the GUI configuration options tell me how I can get this single line of data written to a file. It's only the final results that I'm interested in, ie the **results** of the calculations, not the **data** needed for the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
./jmeter -n -t [Jmeter Location "/home/documents/jmeter.jmx"]  -l [Jmeter results location/home/documents/Results.jtl"]
```

Running Jmeter script in CLI should help you to get this report using above command

Comment: or add this part to get a summary of the test if the test is running in the background.

Comment: ./jmeter -n -t [Jmeter Location "/home/documents/jmeter.jmx"]  -l [Jmeter results location/home/documents/Results.jtl"] > dataLog.log 2>&1 </dev/null &

Answer (score 0):

The values you're looking for are **calculated** after all results are ready, you cannot configure JMeter to save i.e. average response time because it will change with each next result coming to the file. Same applies for other metrics.

Reference material:

- [Metrics Description](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Calculator](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class where you can see exact formulae

If you need to store the metrics like average, min, max, etc. into a CSV file - consider using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) tool which is capable of producing tables and charts out of the .jtl result files so you can use it for automation of the results processing.

Comment: ok, then it very confusing and strange design to have a "Write results to file" option inside a "Summary Report", when the data written is not that summary data.

Comment: Also, the results are actually calculated in the fly, not at the end of the test run.